# Free-form builder

Tags: .net, webforms

I wonder if there is a form builder/editor that I can use for my web site? Preferably .Net based

I'm going to allow site admins to create forms and save them so users can fill in the forms and save the data. I can handle the form and data usage but would prefer to avoid creating the UI if it is possible.

There is a number of free form editors out there but as I understood they all generate HTML you can insert into your website. It is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just a google search away..

http://www.dotnetgoodies.com/form_builder.aspx

Features include:

"On-the-fly form-builder: Create an entire form, complete with an administrative system in minutes."

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: hmmm it seems it complies with the requirements I listed :). I have seen that one but did not understand what it can do. However it seems that it is too complex. Another requirement I know :). sorry for the confusion. but I will have to buy the code and rip off the UI part. I would prefer something else. Even Html5 with its drag-n-drop seems to be a better choice for me.